# how to combine (and add) some value of list of dict in Python 3?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two list of dict :

```
list_of_dict1 = [{'Coin' : 'AAA', 'Price' : '55'},{'Coin' : 'BBB', 'Price' : '45'}] 

list_of_dict2 = [{'Coin' : 'CCC', 'Price' : '77'},{'Coin' : 'AAA', 'Price' : '45'},{'Coin' : 'DDD', 'Price' : '4'}]
```

I want a dict (or list of dict) as :

```
list_of_dict = [{'Coin' : 'AAA', 'Price' : '100'},{'Coin' : 'BBB', 'Price' : '45'},{'Coin' : 'CCC', 'Price' : '77'}]
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: @Anthony1223 this won't work because dictionaries are not hashable

Comment: you can concatenate two lists with `list_of_dict1 + list_of_dict2`. If you want to ensure keys are unique, you'll have to use a loop

Comment: i want to add some value of identical key and have juste one list of dict without doublon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this efficiently, use a `defaultdict` and iterate over each nested entry.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

list_of_dict1 = [{'Coin' : 'AAA', 'Price' : '55'},{'Coin' : 'BBB', 'Price' : '45'}] 
list_of_dict2 = [{'Coin' : 'CCC', 'Price' : '77'},{'Coin' : 'AAA', 'Price' : '45'},{'Coin' : 'DDD', 'Price' : '4'}]

totals = defaultdict(int)
for seq in (list_of_dict1, list_of_dict2):
    for entry in seq:
        totals[entry["Coin"]] += int(entry["Price"])
list_of_dict = [{"Coin": k, "Price": str(v)} for k, v in totals.items()]
```

Result:

```
>>> list_of_dict
[
    {'Coin': 'AAA', 'Price': '100'},
    {'Coin': 'BBB', 'Price': '45'},
    {'Coin': 'CCC', 'Price': '77'},
    {'Coin': 'DDD', 'Price': '4'}
]
```

Note: it looks like `{'Coin': 'DDD', 'Price': '4'}` is excluded from your result and is unclear why. If that is intentional and you want something like only entries that are members of both lists, you would want to keep a counter and weed out those entries that do not have a total count equal to the number of lists.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer.
It works good but :

this was an example. I have this kind of items() (for example)

{'Coin': 'BNB', 'Balance': 1, 'USDT': 618, 'Price': 618.61}

With your method, i obtained just the coin and the balance
I tried to modify and add USDT (some of both dict) and price (updated as : (price1 + price2 /2)

    for seq in (wallet_ftx, wallet_kc):
        #print(seq)
        for entry in seq:
            print(entry)
            totals[entry["Coin"]] += float(entry["Balance"]) += float(entry["USDT"])

But doesn't works, i am just a beginner in python sorry

Comment: if you are here